# Complex binding returning null

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am passing a datasourcerequest object
(https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/api/Kendo.Mvc.UI/DataSourceRequest)

to a .net core 7 webservice with query string of

> page=1&pageSize=10

however it always comes back null no matter if I make the method a get or post. This was working fine in .net 3.1 anyone have any idea why this would stop working or what I can do to diagnosis the issue ?

```
 [Authorize]
    [Route("age{tenantId}/api/[controller]/{action=Index}")]
    [ApiContrpoller]
    public class BillingContractsController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetBillingContracts(DataSourceRequest request)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try add `[FromQuery]` attribute to specific the source,If you don't specific the source,Route data and query string values are used only for simple types by default